# Não consigo fazer insert em orientação objeto

Tags: php

Estou estudando **POO** em **php** e estou com uma dificuldade, estou fazendo uma plataforma simples que usa o **CRUD** (só para treinar).

Criei minhas *class* e e as *views* e mesmo assim não estou conseguindo fazer o *insert*, se eu faço no puro como método antigo ele funciona, já em orientação objeto não

Não sei o que esta acontecendo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue o código

**Model/UserInterno**

```
class UserInterno{

    private $nome;
    private $sobrenome;
    // private $tipo;
    private $email;
    private $login;
    private $senha;


    public function getNome(){
        return $this->nome;
    }

    public function setNome($nome){
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    public function getSobrenome(){
        return $this->sobrenome;
    }

    public function setSobrenome($sobrenome){
        $this->sobrenome = $sobrenome;
    }

    // public function getTipo(){
    //     return $this->tipo;
    // }

    // public function setTipo($tipo){
    //     $this->tipo = $tipo;
    // }

    public function getEmail(){
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email){
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getLogin(){
        return $this->login;
    }

    public function setLogin($login){
        $this->login = $login;
    }

    public function getSenha(){
        return $this->senha;
    }

    public function setSenha($senha){
        $this->senha = $senha;
    }

}
```

**Controller/ServiceUserInterno**

```
class ServiceUserInterno{

    //atributos
    private $db;
    private $user;

    function __construct(Mysqli $mysqli, UserInterno $user){
     //ja recebendo a conexao do banco
     $this->db = $mysqli;
     $this->user = $user;
    }
    public function insert(){
        $stmt = $this->db->stmt_init();
        $stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_user_master (nome, sobrenome, email, login, senha) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");

        $nome_user = $this->user->getName();
        $sobrenome_user = $this->user->getSobrenome();
        // $tipo_user = $this->user->getTipo();
        $email_user = $this->user->getEmail();
        $login_user = $this->user->getLogin();
        $senha_user = $this->user->getSenha();


        $stmt->bind_param("ssisss", $nome_user, $sobrenome_user, $email_user, $login_user, $senha_user);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

**Controller/cadastrarUser_interno**

```
<?php 
include('libs/conexao.php');
require_once ("Model/UserInterno.php");
require_once ("Controller/ServiceUserInterno.php");

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$user = new UserInterno();

$ServiceUser = new ServiceUserInterno($mysqli, $user);


$ServiceUser->setNome($nome);
$ServiceUser->setSobrenome($sobrenome);
$ServiceUser->setEmail($email);
$ServiceUser->setLogin($login);
$ServiceUser->setSenha($senha);

$ServiceUser->insert();
?>
```

**Views/view_criar_usuario_interno**

```
   <div class="row linha_form">
            <form action="../Controller/cadastrarUser_interno.php" method="POST">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome*" class="input_user">
                    <input type="text" name="sobrenome" placeholder="Sobrenome" class="input_user">
                    <!-- <input type="text" name="tipo_area" placeholder="Formação profissional*" class="input_user"> -->
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail*" class="input_user">
                    <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login*" class="input_user">
                    <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha*" class="input_user">
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="Cadastrar" class="btn_cadastrar_user">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

ERRO:  **Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ServiceUserInterno::setNome() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/curso_php_mysql/sistema_KeM/Controller/cadastrarUser_interno.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/curso_php_mysql/sistema_KeM/Controller/cadastrarUser_interno.php on line 17**

> OBS: o arquivo **cadastrarUser_interno** ele recebe os dados do post que foi enviado do formulário e faz o insert

Comment: Qual é exatamente o problema? aparece alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: A linha 6 é `$stmt = $this->db->stmt_init();` ?

Comment: No meu editor aparece nesta linha > private $user;

Comment: Só isso não parece gerar o erro, vc tem alguma linha como `private $prop = new obj()` ou chama alguma função na inicialização da propriedade?

Comment: Desculpa, atualizei a minha pasta no apache (pois tenho que colocar meu controller la no php do apache, se não na hora do require ele não encontra) e aparece este erro... e na hora do set, não sei porque desta forma não vai

Comment: `$ServiceUser` não tem nenhum `setNome` ou `setAlgo` quem tem é propriedade privadade `$user` não tem como chamar externamente. Você já passa o  usuário para `$ServiceUse` nem faz sentido chamar esses `set()` o trabalho é feito 'duas vezes'.

Comment: Não entendi, o que voce quis dizer... Como vou recuperar os dados do post na class ServiceUser....

Comment: Montei uma resposta, qualquer coisa avise.

Answer (score 1):

O erro acontece porque não existe nenhum método `setNome()` ou `setAlgo()` na classe `ServiceUserInterno`. Essa classe tem duas dependências a primeiro objeto do MySQLi e a segundo o objeto `User` veja no construtor.

```
$ServiceUser = new ServiceUserInterno($mysqli, $user);
```

Se `$user` tem `setNome(), setSobrenome()` etc e é passado para classe que faz o insert (`ServiceUserInterno`) qual é sentido do código abaixo?

```
$ServiceUser->setNome($nome);
$ServiceUser->setSobrenome($sobrenome);
$ServiceUser->setEmail($email);
$ServiceUser->setLogin($login);
$ServiceUser->setSenha($senha);
```

Nenhum. Pode remove-lo.

As informações enviadas pelo usuário devem ser guardadas pela classe `UserInterno`. Mude o código para:

```
$user = new UserInterno();

$user->setNome($nome);
$user->setSobrenome($sobrenome);
$user->setEmail($email);
$user->setLogin($login);
$user->setSenha($senha);

$ServiceUser = new ServiceUserInterno($mysqli, $user);
```

Comment: Opa... Obrigado, eu dei uma mudada na minha logica, só que ainda estou muito cru em POO... mas obrigado pela ajuda